# Picture are not shown in all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, images, ssl, security

[image: Picture are not shown]

This is a screen shoot of SE I took from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/474911/what-is-the-rule-to-put-grounding-in-the-circuit-schematic-and-what-is-that-gro). That's mine. But mine or others are the same, not working, no image is shown. That's makes it difficult for me to understand a topic. I have tried with my browsers with various OSes (Windows, Linux, and Android), but they are not working. Even I tried directly with https://i.stack.imgur.com. Also it is not working. Its comment, security problem. This problem began since few months back. It is quite disturbing.

What is that problem, and how can we solve that?

**Additional info**: I am Indonesian and stay in Indonesia. That situation has happened in the capital city and far outside the capital city.

Comment: From the technical side - what happens when you run traceroute and ping on imgur?

Comment: I run command like this with Administrator permission: **C:> ping i.stack.imgur.com** and the comment is, **pinging mypage.blocked.bltsel [114.121.254.4] with 32 bytes of data** then followed by 4 lines comment **Request time out**.

Comment: Definitely an isp/dns hijack. Maybe try another dns server

Answer (score 5):

It appears that imgur.com is continuing to be blocked [in China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websites_blocked_in_mainland_China) (number 69 on the list) and possibly other countries - this is in line with the [Internet Censorship Policy of the people's Republic of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_China) (come to be known as "The Great Firewall of China").

[Indonesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_in_Indonesia#Censorship) too has seen "substantial filtering" of it's internet in a way which is described by the [OpenNet Initiative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenNet_Initiative) as "inconsistent and unsystematic".

As of the date of this question on meta: [As a workaround to Imgur being blocked, is there a image hosting site which allows URL uploads and does not violate CC BY-SA 4.0 copyright?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339029/as-a-workaround-to-imgur-being-blocked-is-there-a-image-hosting-site-which-allo/339035) There is no known complete workaround.

Comment: The user claims to be in Indonesia as per their bio, so the China block doesn't apply (unless they're using a VPN that routes traffic through China).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I couldn't find complete details of blocks per-site per-country , excepting the well known one of China. The Indonesian one is not detailed, but answer amended to clarify, thanks.

Comment: Thank you my friend. That's correct that I am Indonesian and stay in Indonesia. But seems that there is no big incident in Indonesia in this recent few months so our government take action to block some sites. Indeed, around two years back and more there are censorship as any terrorist action.

Comment: I run command like this with Administrator permission: **C:> ping i.stack.imgur.com** and the comment is, **pinging mypage.blocked.bltsel [114.121.254.4] with 32 bytes of data** then followed by 4 lines comment **Request time out**.

Comment: It's difficult to say definitively, but Pt. Telekomunikasi Selular has been repeatedly hacked (possibly by domestic protestors, possibly foreign interests), it's not clear that the allegiance of the many interest of those who own the company are all in line with the Indonesian Government - as it is not clear what the Indonesian Government's allegiances are. [Jacarta](https://www.thejakartapost.com/news/2019/11/07/from-buzzers-to-prosecutions-indonesias-internet-freedom-under-threat.html) and surrounding areas seem to have been particularly targeted by Government censorship for many months.